# how to validate a field twice in form without alert message/popup? sorry if repeated just provide me link

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I am validating a login form. My password field is working perfectly as I want but while validating USERNAME field I'm calling ajax for username validation i.e to check if username exists and after that if username field is empty calling a js function which shows a message but here I'm having a popup message but I wanted to display that message above the textbox. How can i do that?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Please add some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an error holder before the input box.

```
<span style="display:none;color:#E84344;" id='USERNAME_ERROR'> </span>
<input type="text" name="USERNAME" id="USERNAME" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email or User Name" onchange="CheckLoginCustomer('loginform')"/>
```

Following Change you need to do in loginvalidation function

```
     function loginvalidation(formname)
     {  

         var form=document[formname];
         var USERNAME= form.USERNAME.value;
         var PASSWORD= form.PASSWORD.value;
         var userNameFlag = form.userNameFlag.value;


    if(USERNAME == '')
         {

           document.getElementById('USERNAME_ERROR').innerHTML = 'Please Enter Registered UserId';
           document.getElementById('USERNAME_ERROR').style.display = 'block';
          return false;
        }
.....
.....
```

Whereever you dont want to show this error message do the following:

```
 document.getElementById('USERNAME_ERROR').innerHTML = '';
 document.getElementById('USERNAME_ERROR').style.display = 'none';
```

Do the same for others ..

Comment: I think you didn't recognize loginValidation function. If I'll put provide js in loginValidation How will it work?

Comment: But while displaying Invalid email USERNAME_ERR msg should go off and vice-versa. That's what my concern

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Updated but at a time one error message I want as mentioned in my last comment. Hope u"ll get back to me on this

Comment: When you remove the Invalid email anchor tag

Comment: document.getElementById('USERNAME_ERROR').innerHTML = 'Invalid Email';
           document.getElementById('USERNAME_ERROR').style.display = 'block';

Comment: --Do this when it is not valid email

Comment: Its so simple. Do not get confused. "Check the condition if not ok, then change the innerHtml,  If all conditions satisfied,Clear the innerHtml"

Answer (score 0):

i'm making a code for you please check below link:

https://jsfiddle.net/fatehjagdeo/9way7qc2/1/

or check my code below:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="text" id="username"><br>
<input type="password" id="password"><br>
<input type="button" value="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<script>
$(document).on('click','#submit',function(){
$('.error').remove();
var username=$('#username').val();
var password=$('#password').val();
var err=0;
if(username==""){
$('#username').before('<p class="error">Please enter username</p>');
err=1;
}
if(password==""){
$('#password').before('<p class="error">Please enter password</p>');
err=1;
}
if(err==0){
// send your ajax here
}
});
</script>
```